# Recovery of vim running in screen session after crash of Xorg

Tags: xorg, screen, crash, vim, memory-leak

Recently my system become unstable because of a mysterious memory leak. As a result I have the Xorg process frequently killed with `Out of memory` entry in the `/var/log/syslog`.

To save my `vim` session in case of crashes I run it within `screen`.

Unfortunately, after Xorg is killed I am unable to recovery the `vim` session. The reattached shell is totally messed. So far every time I was trying to exit `vim` by issuing `:qa` command at blind. Then with every press of <kbd>Enter</kbd> I get prompt in **the same line**.

I suspect the `vim` is not running (have to validate it after next crash) since:

1. despite I issued the `:qa` command, new `vim` session warns me about presence of the swap file,
2. I can see the `:qa` command in my `.bash_history` file.

Recovery after close of terminal emulator window works fine.

What (but fixing the memory leak) may I do to preserve my `vim` session?

Versions: `vim` - 7.4.52, `screen` - 4.01.00devel, Ubuntu - 14.04.5

[EDIT]
`vim` is definitively not running after crash - today I found a message `ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 12810, errno = 11` in the resumed screen window.

Comment: See if [my post](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5500/205) on [vi.se] helps.

Comment: @muru do you mean to bypass the screen when typing into vim's stdin? I will give it a try after next crash - if the vim is still up.

Comment: Yes. If Vim is up, then the error message about the swap file will say `(still running)` next to the Process ID. If not, you can safely go on to recover from swap and then delete it.

Comment: @muru thanks, I will let you know if it worked

Comment: @muru it is the latter case and it works - I would like to accept your answer if you mind to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Vim complains about a swap file when opening a file, there are two cases: either it's from another currently running Vim process, or it's from a crashed Vim process.

If it's from a running process, the message will look like so:

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".foo.swp"
          owned by: muru   dated: Thu Feb 16 15:59:59 2017
         file name: ~muru/foo
          modified: no
         user name: muru   host name: localhost
        process ID: 870 (still running)
While opening file "foo"
```

Note how it says `(still running)` next to the process ID. An error due to a crashed Vim's swap file won't have that (except, if by coincidence, another currently running process got that same PID). If it's from a crashed Vim, you can choose to recover from the swap file, and later delete it.

If it's from a currently running Vim process, you can kill it (the swap file will let you recover) or choose to gracefully exit if you don't want a swap file lying around. For the latter option, if you don't have `screen` or some such way to interact with the Vim process, you can use Python to send key codes to it, as described in [another post by me.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5500/205)